# Why do ion thrusters frequently use xenon as the reaction mass?

Tags: ion-thruster

From skimming [the Wikipedia article on ion thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster), I notice that xenon is frequently (though not exclusively) used as the reaction mass in systems that have actually been deployed - Deep Space 1, Hayabusa, SMART-1, and Dawn, for example.

What are the properties of xenon that make it attractive for use in ion thrusters? I imagine that its inertness is certainly helpful, but in that case, why xenon as opposed to, say, krypton or some other noble gas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Xenon is the heaviest non-radioactive elemental inert gas. The added mass allows for denser packing at less pressure. The mass is one of the limiting factors, so having a more dense gas helps tremendously.

The limiting factor relates to the mass of the propellant. Essentially, a heavier mass allows for more momentum to come from the overall system. The mass will take longer to accelerate, allowing more momentum to be exerted on the particle. Radioactivity could cause all kinds of issues, as could something that would be reactive. Elemental is easier because it's easier to manipulate, and as you have to make the gas ionic, if it's not elemental it will have a much higher potential to react with something. Thus, it is more efficient to use a heavy elemental non-radioactive inert gas.

Comment: So the pressure on the vessel that contains the reaction mass is a limiting factor here? That comes as a bit of a surprise. Roughly speaking, how much pressure are we talking about here?

Comment: Well, the inert gas law states that the pressure is proportional to the mass of the molecule. So for an equal mass of Xenon vs Krypton, you're talking about a 57% increase in pressure for the same mass of gas.

Comment: @senshin Put another way, the higher pressure the gas needs to be stored under, the stronger the container you need for it.  (Assuming you're not using reactive or radioactive)  Stronger containers generally weigh more, and weight decreases efficiency.

Comment: @PatrickM Ah, now I get it. By using a gas with a high molar mass, you increase the mass required for the _vessel_, and that's a bad thing.

Comment: Increase the mass of the vessel, without actually gaining anything useful as a result.

Comment: Why not use mercury, which is liquid and so does not need a pressure vessel for storage?  It also has a higher mass, and is not highly reactive.

Comment: @jamesqf Just a guess, but might mercury be difficult to ionize?

Comment: Mercury is easier to ionize than Xenon, and has been used/considered in the past.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [wikipedia page on ion thrusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster):

> Ionization energy represents a very large percentage of the energy
>   needed to run ion drives. The ideal propellant for ion drives is thus
>   a propellant molecule or atom that is easy to ionize, that has a high
>   mass/ionization energy ratio. In addition, the propellant should not
>   cause erosion of the thruster to any great degree to permit long life;
>   and should not contaminate the vehicle.

Comment: however, Xe has very high ionization energy, so it would be one of the worst choice by that argument
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy#/media/File:First_Ionization_Energy.svg

Comment: Xe has a lower ionization energy than other noble gasses.

Comment: @ProkopHapala Proportianally to its mass, xenon's ionization energy is low, and more mass makes more thrust, so for that same ionization energy cost, you get more bang for your buck.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently they aren't even restricted to noble elements: [This great paper from AFRL](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a549666.pdf) notes that bismuth is a good contender that has been demonstrated in Hall thrusters.  The drawback with fuels that are not gases at very low temperatures is that:

1. They have to be vaporized, which requires extra energy and engineering.
2. If they are not gaseous at low temperatures then there is (unvalidated) concern that the ions could condense back onto the spacecraft.

> For  high  thrust  to  power  missions,  bismuth  has  been 
>   demonstrated  as  a  viable  alternative  Hall  effect thruster
>   propellant.  Bismuth, with its high atomic mass (209 amu) and low
>   ionization potential (7.3 eV) appears  to  have  advantages  for 
>   missions  where  high  thrust  at  reduced  specific  impulse  is 
>   advantageous, primarily for orbit raising missions.  Bismuth’s main
>   drawback is that the metal must be vaporized to be ionized and
>   accelerated within a Hall effect thruster.  The requirement for high
>   temperatures (boiling point of  1,837K)  require  special 
>   engineering  considerations  compared  to  the  relatively  simple 
>   gas  distribution systems  used  for  xenon.   In  addition,  the  use 
>   of  vapor  as  a  propellant  has  tended  to  cause  concern 
>   for spacecraft operators despite the assurances of thruster developers.
>   The risk of metal redeposition from the propellant  on  solar  arrays 
>   and  sensitive  instruments  is  a  large  concern  that  will 
>   strongly  limit  bismuth’s appeal to spacecraft designers.