# Solar powered spacecraft electrolyzing water as it goes; would ion drives or burning the H +O be more efficient?

Tags: rockets, electric-propulsion

I keep trying to think of ways that future asteroid mining might be facilitated, with cost effective in space transport a major challenge; I have been wondering about different ways that a spacecraft using in-space resources could fuel itself. Hydrogen is cited as possible reaction mass for ion drive but carrying big tanks of it is problematic.

Water that is electrolyzed aboard is one option I thought of and wondered if anyone else has assessed this as on option. Can Oxygen can be used for ion drives as well (in addition to the Hydrogen drives)? Obtaining a preferred "fuel" like Xenon looks impossible. Alternatively, these can be burned in more conventional rockets.

Obtaining water is going to present (relatively) straightforward challenges. It could be a byproduct of or element used by an asteroid mining operation, whereas producing hydrocarbon or other chemical fuels would be more complex. Does anyone know how efficient each of these approaches might be, how they compare?

Comment: Highly related, possibly a duplicate https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48699/6944

Comment: Using oxygen in an ion drive may be a problem, the ionized and accelerated oxygen ions should not destroy the electrode grids of the engine.

Comment: Another strategy is to use solar thermal energy to heat the water. There have been proposals that heat the water to the point where H and  O dissociate (several thousand degrees... temperatures are limited by available materials, not the solar black body temperature). The low molecular weigh (and therefor high speed) increases the potential Isp. At this point I think it is mostly hand waving and Science Fiction, but the idea is interesting.

Comment: @Uwe - I would have expected any ionized gases to be chemically reactive. More chemically reactive for oxygen?

Comment: @Woody - super-charged steam? I lack the skill set to assess the merits. I am supposing they are seeking to reduce the amounts of water needed by increasing the exhaust velocities. Well, my question is probably about the trade-offs each option presents as much as anything. The lack of answers probably reflects how hard it is to make these comparisons.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Whilst the question is different - I deleted the comment I made that I don't think it is a duplicate as the answers DO seem to overlap enough to cover my question. Thanks to those who provided them and to those commenting.

Comment: @KenFabian ... according to the rocket equation (source of all wisdom in rocketry), the specific impulse (rocket efficiency) is proportional to the exhaust velocity. Hotter exhaust = more velocity. Also, lighter molecules (H2 vs H2O) =faster at a given temperature.

Comment: @KenFabian but ionized oxygen may be much more reactive than an ionized noble gas.  There chemical compounds of oxygen and the metals used to build ion engines, but not of noble gases to metal.

Comment: @Uwe - being reactive before it is ionized - pipes, pumps, storage - would make for problems also but surely familiar ones. I did expect absence of physical contact for the ionized gases themselves. I wonder too at the durability and the trade-offs between long duration, low thrust and short periods of high thrust.

Comment: @Woody - with H2O broken apart, to plasma by heat I initially thought that would be chemical energy lost - but not if the result is higher exhaust velocities?

Comment: @KenFabian ...  In the rocket equation , Isp is proportional to the exhaust velocity. For whatever reaction mass you are carrying, the faster you throw it out behind, the more efficient is your rocket. At a given temperature, light molecules are travelling faster than heavy ones.

Comment: @KenFabien ... This is why gas core reactor nuclear rockets propose to use hydrogen as propellant. In chemical rockets, the energy source is also the reaction mass. So you are limited in the choice of reaction mass ... it must be combustion products. Nuclear and solar rockets separate power source from reaction mass, so they are free to chose what gives highest Isp, assuming you have a way to store the propellant. Come to think of it, a solar rocket IS a gas core nuclear rocket !